# How do I change class object attributes once they've been created in Python?

Tags: python, game-development

I am trying to create object attributes which can be modified later depending on user inputs

The gist of it is that I'm trying to make a Text Based RPG with stats. I made the Player a class object with stats like 'HP' 'AC' 'Strength' and the like.

A core part of the game is the stats being able to interact with each other. For instance, a player's 'AC' is calculated by adding 10 and their 'Dex' modifier

I want to let the player choose their 'Dex' so I need to be able to modify the object attributes accordingly

However, Python doesn't seem to recognize the math I put into it.

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 1
    self.y = 2
    self.z = self.x + self.y

test = Test()
test.y = 7
print(str(test.z))
```

the print gives me '3'

How can I make it so that the it gives me '8'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want attribute value computed at access this is task for `@property` decorator, consider following example:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.x + self.y

player1 = Player()
player1.y = 7
print(player1.z)
```

Output:

```
8
```

If you want to know more about decorators in python I suggest reading [realpython Primer on python decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It's about 2:45 am where I am right now, This problem has kept me up late lol, so I will try this in the morning...err afternoon I guess.

Thanks again!

Comment: It worked! Thanks a million. Now I'm going to read the primer and find out WHY it worked. lol